Looking to find a fantasy painting with a knight on horseback overlooking a distant castle. Probably 70's or 80's
The knight is on the left of the castle in the distance. He's wearing a long cloak, and the horse's head is bowed. I think :|
It may also have been an album cover but I would not swear to it. It was a popular poster all those years ago. I'd love to find a copy of it again now.

This is a bit tropey and generic.  Is the knight above the castle looking down or below it looking up?  What are the predominant colours?  Is the art style closer to Rodney Matthews or Hildebrandt?

What does this have to do with science fiction or fantasy? Why do you call it a "fantasy painting"?

In addition to what user14111 said, this seems... pretty broad. Knight, castle, 70s or 80s ("probably")- additional details would help about knight's pose, colour scheme, time of day, size of castle etc would all help

Well it's all I had guys. Of course more detail would help. But it was not there in the memory.

I know we have an answer, but the album cover close to that description that leaps to mind is the self-titled Molly Hatchet album from 1978. No castle though. The painting, Death Dealer inspired works in just about every media imaginable.

My guess would be Gustave Doré - Idylls of the King. This one is from the 19th century though


Used as an album cover by Norwegian black metal band Dimmu Borgir's For all tid

+1 Winner, winner, chicken dinner!

Yes, this is the picture. I'm so pleased. Thank you for being able to figure it out from such a woeful dearth of information.

Perhaps one of these may ring a bell for you…
  
  
  

No album cover. No popular poster.

Exactly zero of those covers features a knight on the left of a castle!

@TonyK Correct, though The Pastel City is pretty close. Given how fallible / lossy recall is, being liberal in interpreting the author's memory could be helpful, as could similar images

@bertieb: Yes, you're right -- that building in the distance could be a castle. But no long cloak. And I would say it's the corpses of the enemy that grab the attention, not the castle!

@TonyK Just goes to show how selective visual attention is- I didn't notice the corpses until you mentioned them! Now, let me find that video of people throwing a basketball back and forth while a gorilla walks past... ;-P

@DavidNoble OTOH I love Frazzetta! :)

I'm misting up - I've read a lot of these books over the years. Good stuff.

This is probably the 1973 fantasy painting Death Dealer by Frank Frazetta.
It was used as the album cover for the 1978 debut album by southern rock band Molly Hatchet.
A 15 x 22 vintage art print can be purchased directly from the Frazetta Art Museum.
A 24 x 36 modern poster print can be purchased on Amazon.
You can easily find various other sizes available by searching "Death Dealer poster" on Google, eBay, etc.

No knight. No castle. No overlook.

Great artwork, but not the one. However I am glad you posted since I enjoyed seeing Frank's work.

Could be The Rider
This is another Frank Frazetta. It's got a rider with a long cloak, horse with head bowed, and a castle in the distance.
He's not very knight-like - but otherwise it fits.
It was used as the cover art for an Edgar Rice Burroughs novel in 1974, and has probably been in prints / posters since about then.

